# What is a Whispers of the Old Gods pack?

Tags: hearthstone

I recently started playing Hearthstone and in the launcher was announced that the "Whispers of the Old Gods" had arrived. And in the blog there was said that if you log in you should get 3 Whispers of the Old God packs. But I didn't get anything so I was confused because I couldn't find if it was a expansion pack or not.

If you know the answer please say if it is a expansion pack and tell me how to get it.

Answer (score 9):

Whispers of the Old Gods is an expansion in Hearthstone similar to The Grand Tournament and Goblin vs. Gnomes.

To get these free packs, you have to win a certain amount of games in the Standard format, and there will be another quest to get more packs after you completed the first quest. So check your quests.

This expansion came out maybe a month ago? So I wouldn't be surprised if your window of opportunity has passed, however, you should get a free C'thun card.

EDIT: When I say "pack", I mean a pack of cards, not an expansion pack.

Comment: Just confirming what @bmarkhan said, you will get a free "C'thun" and 2 "Beckoner of Evil" when you open your first Whisper of Old Gods pack, as that is not related to the launch promotion of the 3 free packs.

("blue post": http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/20742894484#11)

Comment: In a forum thread ([link](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/20743644345)) several people report, that they also didn't receive any of the three free packs. No official word from Blizzard, but apparently, you can open a ticket which will eventually give the packs to you.